# Customize the UI of selected item in indicator view .NET Maui

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I want to make the UI of selected item in indicator view using Data Template.
For the selected Item, the indicator view should be elongated and rest of all should be sphere.
The UI is as follows :

[image: elongated view for selected Item]

Is this possible in .NET MAUI

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you can achieve it by using `Frame` and [`VisualState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/indicatorview?view=net-maui-8.0#set-visual-states):

```xml
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="IndicatorFrameStyle"
           TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                    Value="LightGray" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                    Value="#FF000F" />
                                <Setter Property="WidthRequest"
                                    Value="45" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout Margin="10">
        ...
        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                   Margin="0,0,0,40"
                   IndicatorColor="Transparent"
                   SelectedIndicatorColor="Transparent"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame Margin="10"
                       CornerRadius="50"
                       HeightRequest="20"
                       WidthRequest="20"
                       Style="{StaticResource IndicatorFrameStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
        </IndicatorView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/oH34zQa).

**Update**

It's best to use `Border`. From the Frame docs, the Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead. Similarly, BoxView isn't recommended, and it doesn't do quite the same thing as a Border. Although BoxView can mimic simple graphics, a better alternative is to use .NET MAUI Shapes or .NET MAUI Graphics.

```xml
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="IndicatorBorderStyle"
           TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                ...
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout Margin="10">
        ...
        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                   Margin="0,0,0,40"
                   IndicatorColor="Transparent"
                   SelectedIndicatorColor="Transparent"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="10"
                       StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 50"
                       HeightRequest="20"
                       WidthRequest="20"
                       Style="{StaticResource IndicatorBorderStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
        </IndicatorView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This looks great but shouldn't you be using Border here?

Comment: Border can also replace Frame, and BoxView can also be used.